# Error while running PHP project

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Am running a project based on PHP for the first time in my machine, got error in php-sdk path saying `Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension`. What should be done to make it work ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the curl php extension. 
   Follow this steps to enable

1. Install php curl
     **sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl php5-mcrypt**
2. Open **php.ini** file and add this line  after finish installation

   **extension=curl.so**
3. Restart the apache server

   **/etc/init.d/apache2 restart**
4. Then in a new php page type:

   ```
   <?php
     phpinfo();
   ?>
   ```

   You will find curl is included in php info page.